# Document Versioning

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, versioning

If I don't explicitly mention the number of versions and uncheck `Keep the following number of major versions` in Versioning Settings of a document library then does it holds the maximum value of 400,000 as defined by Microsoft in this [TechNet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
There could be 400k major versions and 511 minor versions apart from your current version.

But the better practice would be to set a limit nonetheless. You could set something like 100, which won't be hit in years, and that would be sufficient for all practical purposes.

Comment: Curious as to why this is the better practice? Does it take up less HDD? I can imagine in many old intranets a given arbitrary limit could be exceeded with no one knowing

Comment: That's one of the considerations, yes. Plus since major versions will be stored as separate files on database, even if there are relatively small changes to the file, a 1MB file with 1000 major version will take up 1GB. And when your DB hits the 200GB mark, you will have no clue which files are eating up the space.

Comment: True, although it depends on the business case as many documents need a complete audit trail (Payroll, HR, etc) as such the HDD will just have to be expanded.

Comment: Roland has put the right question in. I don't see this as a best practice in setting a limit. The number depends on organization policy. I just wanted to know about the max value in case I don't mention the number of major versions and I got the answer.

Comment: I agree that for business cases which require a detailed audit trail, you cannot limit the number of versions. But how frequent would such a business case be? And in my answer I am not saying "best practice", I am saying it is a *better* practice to have a limit on the versions rather than not have any. Anyway, I have raised a separate question for this discussion: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174590/configuring-versioning-for-audit-sensitive-data